# How do I put a border around images I upload?

Tags: feature-request

When adding an answer with lots of images ([such as this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24559/tagging-a-friend-in-a-node/100933#100933)), there is no easy way to distinguish between the text and the image. Please allow to put some border around the image. It will make answers much more readable.

Is it the right place to ask for such a feature?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138594/225745 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202696/225745 And my personal opinion is: if you feel your image needs a border, you can add it on your computer before upload. If I post a screenshot of a table, loosing some pixels of width for an extra border it does not need seems bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there isn't a way to add a border to an image, and attributes added to an image tag are filtered out, the easier workaround is to wrap the image with a quote block, such as in the following case.

> [image: Selection popup]

```
> ![Selection popup][10]
```

It doesn't add a border, but it makes the background color different from the page one, and it makes the screenshot more evident.